# Run VB.net app on second monitor

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multiple-monitors

I'm a newbie at coding but I have done simple application for the plan I work for!!

I recently encounter a "little" issue with one of my application!

I build a Windows Form application, with multiple form, that run on a dual screen CNC.  The CNC program have to run on the primary screen at a higher resolution. My application run on the second screen who is a touch screen at 1024;768.

The problem itself is if I run the code with the debug data everything run as I want, open the application on second screen and all the next form open on this screen.  If I install it with the released data, all form open on the primary monitor, even if I drag them on second screen.  After I closed them, they return on the primary.

Is there a way I can put a code line at the beginning of each form who make all form open on the secondary screen.

When the setup will work correctly I'll lock the screen setup just to be sure nobody will mess with the settings.

Please be gentle with me I don't have any formation on how to code.  I learn from myself with reading on the web!!

Thanks all!!

Comment: See [Screen.AllScreens Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @LarsTech, thanks for the upp, I already saw this fonction, but have no clue how to use it!!  As stated above, I don't have any formation on VB.NET coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should position the window at offset 100, 100 on the first non-primary screen found.  You can adjust the location and/or size to suit your needs.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim secondaryMonitor = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) Not x.Primary)
    If secondaryMonitor IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim newLocation = secondaryMonitor.Bounds.Location
        newLocation.Offset(100, 100) ' adjust as needed
        Me.Location = newLocation
        ' Also see Me.Size and Me.Bounds
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Work like charm. Thanks so much!! 
Little down side, I have to put this string on every form.  Try to put it in a class but the 'me.location' does work since I'm not in a form!!

Comment: @Boushard If you want to do this in another class, you can just pass the form instance (`Me`) as a parameter to the method - e.g. `Sub MoveToSecondaryMonitor(form As Form)` and use `form.Location`, then just call `MoveToSecondaryMonitor(Me)` in the form.

Comment: You're the man, everything work as I want!!
Thank you very much sir!!!  You save me a bunch of time!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Private Sub _MainForm_Move(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Move
         ' preserve  me.Location.x  and  me.Location.y  here.
End Sub

Then, at program boot, restore:       me.Location.x  and  me.Location.y
```